How to get the last non-blank line of a terminal buffer running a specific program?
As per text. I have a terminal buffer running ipython and I want capture the last non-blank line.
I tried the following:
var bufnr = bufnr('IPYTHON')
term_getline(bufnr, line('$'))
term_getline(bufnr, line('w$'))

but none term_getline of above produced the desired result.

The bufnr('IPYTHON') will not return the correct buffer number.
If you have only one terminal you could do:
var bufnr = term_list()[0]
getbufline(bufnr, '$')[0]

If you have more than one then you have to determine the right one using either the content using term_getline or the name using getbufferinfo(bufnr)[0].name
An alternative is:
var bufnr = term_list()[0]
var cursor = term_getcursor(bufnr)
term_getline(bufnr, cursor)


Correct! Even after your correction, it won't return the last non-blank line. After what is returned, there are at least another 2 non-blank lines :/.

In my tests getbufline gives good result. I have adapted the solution.

I finally found some for testing it. For terminal buffers running a shell it works. However, if I <c-w>N I see the last line of the buffer corresponds to a non-blank line. If I am running ipython and I hit <c-w>N, then the last non-blank line (which display just a prompt) is followed by  a number of blank lines until the end of the screen. For this reason I want to capture the last non-blank line rather than the last line.

Thanks for the feedback. For the last non blank line I suppose you can use the same API but for a range of line and filter out the blank one. Is that working?

I can't reproduce the problem you mention on Windows. But I have proposed a version that user the term_* API that is maybe more robust :-)

The latter solution works perfectly! Thanks!

Thanks for the feedback. I will edit the answer accordingly :-)

In addition to getting the right buffer, passing line('$') to a function for another buffer won’t work; line() translates lines for the current buffer:
        The result is a Number, which is the line number of the file
        position given with {expr}.  The {expr} argument is a string.
[…]
            $       the last line in the current buffer

Instead you should probably pass '$' directly to term_getline, although that's not documented to work. You could also use the {winid} argument to line to make it get a line from a different window, but that doesn't help if the buffer is hidden.
Thus getbufline is probably the best solution for '$'/last line specifically.

Tested. But that returns the last line, not the last non-blank line. As commented in the previous answer, that works if the terminal buffer is running &shell. But if you run another program, like ipython, the last non-blank line may be followed by a bunch of blank lines.

To find the last non-blank line of a terminal buffer running a specific program, I come up with this function:
vim9script

def LastNonBlankLine(bufnrr: number): number
    var current_buf = bufnr()
    exe $'buffer {bufnrr}'
    var l = line('$')
    exe $'buffer {current_buf}'
    while l > 0 && getbufline(bufnrr, l)[0] =~ '^\s*$'
        l -= 1
    endwhile
    return l
enddef

var bufnr = term_list()[0]
var lastline = LastNonBlankLine(bufnr)
echom "lastline: " .. string(lastline)

Any improvement suggestion is welcome.
